# Does CSS-in-JS not prevent browser from CSS caching?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jss, css-in-js

I am looking for best practices to style React app with Server-Side Rendering.

I see different options like using preprocessors like SASS or putting stylings inside JS code like JSS, styled-components etc.

Playing around JSS, I see that it puts stylings to head section inside HTML. I just use the following example to see the behavior:

https://github.com/cssinjs/examples/tree/gh-pages/react-ssr

Wouldn't it prevent browsers from caching CSS to put it inside head section and hence increase successive page loading time? Is there any way to put styling to an external file with JSS so that browser can cache it?

Answer (score 1):

What you see in that example is Critical CSS. It is only CSS that is used specifically on that view, it is not supposed to be cached, it is faster than loading an external resource in a blocking way and pay with latency.

Critical CSS is an actual performance optimisation here.

Comment: I understand that it is better to load HTML with required CSS for that page inside head section rather than waiting for a blocking CSS load. It is fair enough. My concern is about following page loads. Assuming that we have a big styling data for the page, every time we refresh the page, we would have to load the same big bundle of HTML+CSS while we could utilize browser caching.

Comment: Thats why we need the CSS that is actually used on the page, not everything that potentially might be used after user actions happen. Usually its not that much and compared to the latency price, this tradeoff is better.

Comment: Thats also why CSSinJS is a big deal, because it knows what CSS is actually used.

Comment: Another point is that those optimisations especially make sense for single page applications.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, if I would use a single blocking CSS file for the whole app of React SSR app, it would take a little time to load the page and user would see an empty page for a while. After that, each reload of a page would be faster unless Browser cache is not cleared. On the other hand, if I would use CSSinJS, it would load only necessary CSS inside head section, which is faster than loading the whole CSS, but it would do the same thing for page reloads. As you say, it seems to be a tradeoff in terms of page load speed.

Comment: Yes, it pays off when you have a SPA or relatively small payload of critical CSS.